# Ubuntu 18.04 зависает при воспроизведении аудио

Tags: ubuntu, аудио, pulseaudio

И так. Для того, чтобы воспроизвести проблему необходимо в "Звук" или Pavucontrol включить встроенное аудио и включить музыку либо видео. Зависает в разных промежутках времени. От 1 минуты до нескальких часов. Причем, если запускать игру со звуком, то зависает гораздо реже, чем при воспроизведении аудио. Температура всех узлов нормальная. При зависании REISUB не помогает, только хард резет.
Если выключить звуковухи, то зависания не происходят от слова совсем, тоже самое наблюдается после удаления pulseaudio. Но звука, собственно, нет. Аудио выходы есть, как с зади системника, так и с фронта. Разницы абсолютно никакой нет, куда подключаться.

Версия ядра сейчас - 4.20.5. На предыдущих проблема тоже возникала, поэтому и решил поставить посвежее.
Изначально был стандартный гном, который идет из коробки с 18.04. Сейчас стоит Mate.

journalctl -b 0 -p 0..3 выводит вот такие строки:

```
09 14:15:56 qxcoder-desktop spice-vdagent[1117]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
09 14:16:16 qxcoder-desktop spice-vdagent[1511]: Cannot access vdagent virtio channel /dev/virtio-ports/com.redhat.spice.0
09 14:16:19 qxcoder-desktop pulseaudio[1402]: [pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.TimedOut: Failed to activate service 'org.bluez': timed out (service_start_tim
09 14:42:28 qxcoder-desktop pulseaudio[1675]: [pulseaudio] pid.c: Daemon already running.
```

Железо:

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 6 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.1 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.2 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB Universal Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1d.7 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation H55 Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 4 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.5 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 2 port SATA IDE Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107 [GeForce GTX 750 Ti] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0fbc (rev a1)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller (rev 05)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 1st Generation Core i3/5/7 Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

Comment: если загрузить с флешки тоже лагает звук?

Comment: Хорошая идея, вечером потещу - отпишу :) Спасибо!

Comment: Протестил с лайва в течении часа. Всё хорошо. А не с лайва есть проблемы. Тогда в какую сторону смотреть? Какие логи глянуть и выложить?

Comment: ну логично же что в сторону дров. пробуй дрова выбрать на видюху другие. там в опциях есть такое типа проприетарное по и ещё какое то.

Comment: @JamesM, спасибо за ответ, а дрова на видюху как-то влияют? Её я выключаю и аудио поток идет через встроенное аудио. Да и с дровами на Нвидиа эксперементировал, разницы нет. Даже если ставить nouveau, проблема остается. В какую сторону еще можно посмотреть?